# OpenStreetMap (OSM) POI tools/API

Tags: openstreetmap, point-of-interest

Currently I'm working with OSM. I just need to use it's POI tools/API - https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/POI_tools/API in order to receive data in json format. But I can't understand what the URL for the request to API. In the wiki there is example like: /tag/amenity/restaurant/all/ids.json?bbox= [your bbox]

Please, could anyone provide me a really working example with API url requst?

I'm just confused how all this OSM works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you stumbled upon some dead project (POI tools). What are you really trying to achieve?

Take a look Overpass API instead. The [Overpass_API Language_Guide](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide) has lots of useful examples for retrieving specific POIs in a given area.

There is also a nice frontend available: https://overpass-turbo.eu/. Try using the wizward and search for simple [tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags) like [amenity=restaurant](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:amenity%3Drestaurant). Example: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/yR6. Check the export button as well as the Overpass API documentation about various output formats.

Comment: What i actually need is just receive data in json format , and add markers on it. I'm using open layers as main constructor of the map. So ' i thought , that when i shall receive data , it will contains additional info + maybe images , and then i could add markers and pop-ups . So that's the idea

Comment: The web should have some examples for combining OpenLayers with Overpass API.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot, one more time! I will investigate it